# Formatted my windows drive by mistake and now windows installation cannot find drives

Tags: partitioning, windows

I formatted my laptop's Windows loader partition (ext4) while installing Ubuntu 15.04, and when I tried reinstalling Windows, it can't find any drives.

I already formatted the Linux drive into NTFS with gparted,
and I have another NTFS partition in my computer, yet still, my Windows 8 setup cannot find a single parition for me to install it on.

PS: The Linux installation failed with

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.
this is a fatal error
```

and now I can't do anything.

Comment: Bios or Uefi boot? Mbr or Gpt partition table? Paste a screenshot of Gparted.

Comment: @kyodake the laptop isn't with my right now it's my friends, and I'm pretty sure its bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no data on the hdd (which seems to be the case) do the following. Please note that any and all existing data on the drive will be destroyed after executing the following list.

- Boot from a live cd
- Open console (terminal)
- type sudo -i (you should become root here)
- type dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=2M count=100
- fire up gparted and split the disk into 3 parts

  - 500mb primary partition (service partition for windows)
  - windows partition
  - linux partition
- do not format the partitions
- Start your windows install and let it format the partitions itself (the first 2 only)
- Now install linux

Comment: There is about 300gb data on it on the other partition

Comment: Then probably ask in a windows forum. Probably the windows boot partition is mangled (it should be fairly small initial partition around 500 or less mb). Restoring this to working order should be possible from the windows installer but no idea how exactly.

Comment: what type do i parition it into, GPT or what?

Comment: Your choice. Linux can handle GPT.

Comment: Partitioned with msdos